# Register phantomjs node to Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-grid, ghostdriver

I am currently running Selenium Grid 3.4.0 and phantomjs 2.1.1 on a windows platform.

When I try to register a phantomjs node onto my hub the following error occurs:

```
K:phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe --webdriver=8080 
--webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://IP:5786 
[ERROR - 2017-06-05T13:35:55.135Z] GhostDriver - main.fail - 
{"line":85,"sourceU
RL":"phantomjs://code/main.js","stack":"global 
code@phantomjs://code/main.js:85:56"}
```

phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error

Does anyone know how to get around this error?
Currently my hub is running 5 instances of Firefox, 5 instances of chrome and 1 instance of IE.

```
[ERROR - 2017-06-06T14:36:23.920Z] GhostDriver - main.fail - 
{"line":97,"sourceURL":"phantomjs://platform/hub_register.js","stack":
"register@phantomjs://platform/hub_register.js:97:79\nglobal 
code@phantomjs://code/main.js:78:37"}
```

I ran it again and this time, that is what the error message said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used Phantomjs 1.9.8 and it worked...

Comment: Please accept your answer (once stackoverflow lets you do so), so that the question can be marked closed.

Comment: Yes, I will do so. I'm not sure why I have to wait a day though.